# Android - java - count words

Tags: java, android, string

I have an edittext and I want to count the words in it. There is something wrong when there are new lines in the edittext.

I tried this:

```
String[] WC = et_note.getText().toString().split(" ");
Log.i("wordcount", "wc: " + WC.length);
```

This is a text -> wc: 4

This is

a

text  -> wc: 4

This is

a simple

text -> wc: 4

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to split on arbitrary strings of whitespace, rather than just space characters. So, use `.split("\\s+")` instead of `.split(" ")`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest to use [BreakIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html). According to my experience this is the best way to cover not standard languages like Japanese where there aren't spaces that separates words.

Example of word counting [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/breakiterator.html).

Comment: I created a simple String extension function in Kotlin which uses BreakIterator. Checkout my [Gist](https://gist.github.com/ElegyD/65ad990d505ee20239ef5a3c16eec951)

Answer (score 3):

This would work even with multiple spaces and leading and/or trailing spaces and blank lines:

```
String words = str.trim();
if (words.isEmpty())
return 0;
return words.split("\\s+").length; // separate string around spaces
```

You could also use \\W here instead of \\s, if you could have something other than space separating words.

Answer (score -1):

Late answer but i do it like this

String a = text.replaceAll("\s+","+");

String b = a.replaceAll("[^+]", "");

textview1.setText(String.valueOf((long)(b.length() + 1)));

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.