# how to count the number of words in Kotlin Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I have tried to read this thread: [Android - java - count words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402948/android-java-count-words)

but it doesn't work for me.

so let say I have these words in the android multiline edit text:

---

I

am

very very

happy

right now

---

so I want to count the number of words and then get integer '7' from that multiline edit text. how to do that ?

I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
multilineEditText.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

                val words = s.toString().trim()
                numberOfInputWords = words.split("\\s+").first().length
                wordsCounterTextView.text = "$numberOfInputWords"


            }

        })
```

but this code doesn't work for me, because it doesn't show the right number.

from the thread [Android - java - count words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402948/android-java-count-words)

it is said that I can use `someString.split("\\s+").length`

but I can't access `.length` after using `.split("\\s+")`. like this

[image]

thats why I use `first()` in my code, even though it doesn't work either.

Comment: How exactly is that not working? Are you getting an unexpected value? Is it crashing? Is your device exploding? What did you find out when you debugged it? At which specific point is it going wrong? What have to tried in attempting to remedy the current issue, whatever that might be?

Comment: @MikeM. I am sorry, I have edited my question and I have added the reason now

Comment: `words.split("\\s+".toRegex()).size`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split space from string not working in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48379981/split-space-from-string-not-working-in-kotlin)

Comment: @underoid yup thats the answer

Answer (score 5):

The only problem you have is you are using [Kotlin's split](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html) method which returns a **list of String** whereas [Java's split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method returns an **array of strings**. You should be accessing **size** property since the return of split method here is **List**.

```
  val words = s.toString().trim()
  numberOfInputWords = words.split("\\s+".toRegex()).size
  wordsCounterTextView.text = "$numberOfInputWords"
```

[image: Example for kotlin's split method]

Answer (score 1):

So, you could count the words by the number of newlines and spaces between them. Of course consecutive newlines and consecutive spaces count as one.

There might be a space/newline at the beginning and end. You remove that with `trim()`. The last word won't have a space/newline now, so you need to add 1.

```
val string = "Hello\nWorld"
val count = Regex("""(\s+|(\r\n|\r|\n))""").findAll(string.trim()).count() + 1
println(count) // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This will count how many words are in a given String.

```kotlin
fun wordCount(str: String): Int {
    val trimmedStr = str.trim()
    return if (trimmedStr.isEmpty()) {
        0
    } else {
        trimmedStr.split("\\s+".toRegex()).size
    }
}
```

It also has a fix for some of the other answers which incorrectly return 1 when given an empty string (`""`).

Answer (score 0):

replace all \n with space
and split(" ");
get count of splited string

in java:

```
int count = multilineEditText.getText().toString().replace("\n", " ").split(" ").length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cool RegEx to do what you want (\s|\n)+

```
someString.split("(\\s|\\n)+")
```

Here is a great app to test RegEx : https://regexr.com/