# How to count word in TextView Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, textview

Suppose In my app I have two textview, first one name is `ViewText` and the second one is `WordCount`.

I want to show some text in `ViewText` and `WordCount` shows how many words in `ViewText`.

[image: Here is an example of my UI.]

How can I count words in textview in Android Studio?

Comment: I believe this answer will help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55426910/how-to-count-the-number-of-words-in-kotlin-android/55428548

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```js
val words = "Hi this is sentence for counting words"
var totalCount = words.split("\\s+".toRegex()).size
println(totalCount)
```